# how to get expired domain names by python

Tags: python, dns, whois

I am writing a function by python to get a list of expired domains just like [this one](http://www.domaintools.com/buy/dropping-names/details/?min_date=2011-08-26), but I can not find any library can do this, any ideas about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://github.com/richardpenman/whois (first Google search result when searching for `python whois`). This allows you to determine the expiration date of a domain. But you will need to get a list of domains to check from somewhere (domaintools apparently gets them from domain auctions).

Comment: The author moved the repo to GitHub: https://github.com/richardpenman/whois

Answer (score -1):

Why should there be a library for this kind of work? You probably have to build up your own database of WHOIS information and your own logic.